# In GCD, are all tasks in a serial queue guaranteed to run in the same thread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

In GCD, are all tasks in a serial queue (e.g. main queue) guaranteed to run in the same thread?

Comment: I'm not sure why @vcsjones deleted his answer, as it seems to answer your question with a resounding "no".

Comment: @trojanfoe with the exception of the main queue, in which case the answer is "yes".

Comment: @AaronBrager His answer covered that as well.

Comment: @trojanfoe My apologies, I didn't see his answer, just your comment.

Answer (score 6):

For serial queues generally, no.  From [the Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html):

> Serial queues (also known as private dispatch queues) execute one task
>   at a time in the order in which they are added to the queue. The
>   currently executing task **runs on a distinct thread (which can vary
>   from task to task)** that is managed by the dispatch queue.

For the main queue specifically, yes:

> The main dispatch queue is a globally available serial queue that
>   executes tasks on the application’s main thread. […] Because it runs on your application’s main
>   thread, the main queue is often used as a key synchronization point
>   for an application.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means by "key synchronization point"? Can 't you achieve the synchronization with private dispatch queue?

Comment: It means that applications commonly synchronize data resources on the main queue.  For example, you can have an NSMutableArray of UIImage objects, which are created on a background queue, and then added to the array on the main thread.  If all actions with the NSMutableArray are done on the main thread, the array's synchronization point is the main thread.  You can also, if you want, synchronize a resource on a private serial queue, as you mentioned.  But you should only access this resource through this queue unless you have some other locking mechanism.

Comment: @Boon you could achieve synchronisation with any serial queue, e.g. one specific to a module, but the system beyond your borders uses the main queue for anything that may cross into or out of your code. It's partly to do with having the resource be commonly known and partly to do with being compatible with code that works in terms of the main runloop.